# problems with xcolor package

Tags: errors, color

I am getting the following error with the example given at the end:

Option clash for package xcolor.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,pxfonts,eulervm,xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\usepackage{geometry}

\oddsidemargin = -2cm
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\setcounter{framenumber}{-1}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    contenidos...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to beamer already loading `xcolor`. Two workarounds:

Do not load xcolor with options, and

- write in the preamble:

  `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,table}{xcolor}`

(Note `usenames` is obsolete)

- Add `dvipsnames,svgnames,table` to the class options.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: from beamer manuel, pp 19:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=⟨list of options⟩]{beamer}
```

In your case:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,pxfonts,eulervm,xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry}

\oddsidemargin = -2cm
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\setcounter{framenumber}{-1}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{DarkMagenta}\color{white}}cc}
    a & b   \\
    c & d   \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Only the obsolete `usenames` is given as an argument to `xcolor` in your code.

Comment: According to `beamer` documentation, should be given all. I tested table option and it work.

Comment: Compare what you've quoted from the documentation with what you've written. `table` works for the same reason it works in Bernard's answer. It is not being passed via the `xcolor` option of the class, though. It is being passed as a distinct option.

Comment: Well, than I do not understand the Beamer documentation. Anyway, I tested my solution and it works, meaning, that `dvipsnames` as well `svgnames` are passed to `xcolor` package. The same is valid for option (parameter) `table`.

Comment: Yes, but Bernard already showed that. Of course it works. There is a difference between `\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{beamer}` and `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}`. The former passes `svgnames` and `table` as independent options. Only `dvipsnames` is passed as `xcolor=dvipsnames` to Beamer. The latter passes `xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}` to Beamer.

Comment: Try `\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,handout,svgnames,table]{beamer}` and `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,handout,svgnames,table}]{beamer}`.

Comment: I try both, but don't observe the difference.  I will correct my answer as you suggest.

Comment: You need 2 slides. Try `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,handout,svgnames,table}]{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
 abc
 \onslide<2->
 def
  \end{frame}
\end{document}` versus `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table},handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
 abc
 \onslide<2->
 def
  \end{frame}
\end{document}` You should get 1 slide in the first case, 2 in the second. (I'm surprised there's no complaint in the first, but I guess it just ignores the option.)